# How to change the design size of the application for each and every mobiles?

Tags: android, cordova, size, screen

I have designed my phonegap android application using html and javascript.This application is for mobile.So i want to know how to get the same design size in all the mobiles

I have changed the pixels into dip for width and height of the controls.But i need to get the curve around the border.when i use the px as dip am not getting correctly.And i have given the permission for support screens in android manifest file.

Please tell me the solution.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that the entire screen is filled, your HTML should contain the following in the "head" section:

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "user-scalable=no,width=device-width" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You really need to look into using responsive web design techniques to support the multiple screen sizes and orientations. This is a great book on the topic:

http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design

and a good collection of articles on Smashing Magazine:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/22/responsive-web-design-techniques-tools-and-design-strategies/